# Yii2 login through WordPress using curl

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, yii2

I am using WordPress and Yii2 on same server for single project.

I am expecting flow as if user login from WordPress he/she should login in Yii too.

So I am using curl which send request from WordPress to Yii along with email and password for login into Yii.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://demo.com/loginsupplierwp"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=".$author_obj->user_email."&password=".$password);

$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Even I am able to see `PHPSESSID` in cookies along with request but user unable to login.

The URL works fine if I use get request and enter it directly into browser.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you disable CSRF and make a try?

Comment: you can also use default action `site/login` for this with username and password as  POST parameters

Comment: @SudharshanNair i am using ` public function beforeAction($action) { 

  $this->enableCsrfValidation = false; 

  return parent::beforeAction($action); 

 }` this for disabling CSRF verification already but curl still not working.... also i am using custom login functionality

Comment: user unable to login > You mean are you entering URL in browser?

Comment: @SudharshanNair just for testing purpose i tried passing data directly into url and it works file then i send same request using curl ( only change is that data is in post) and it's not working

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()){}else{echo '<pre>';print_r($model->getErrors());exit;}`
Also try this to get if you are getting any errors

Comment: @SudharshanNair no i am not getting any error at remote action also there is nothing in curl `echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176103/discussion-between-sudharshan-nair-and-paritosh-mahale).

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending login credentials via curl to login action, you're authenticating **curl client**, not the actual user who logged into WordPress. The authentication and session cookie from Yii app is never sent to user, so he is not logged-in. You would need to check what cookies are set in response to curl request and resend it to user.

But the whole idea looks wrong and it will give you many problems. You should try installing some plugin for WordPress which provide OAuth server, and use its api to authenticate your Yii app user.